# How to install Ultisnips with Snippets on Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, git

I'm using Slackware and trying to install and use Ultisnips.

I use Pathogen and the documentation says the following:
>

> Using Pathogen: *UltiSnips-using-pathogen*
>
> If you are a pathogen user, you can track the official mirror of
>   UltiSnips on github: >
>
> $ cd ~/.vim/    $ git submodule add
>   git://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips.git bundle/ultisnips
>
> If you also want the default snippets, also track >
>
> $ git submodule add https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git
>
> See the pathogen documentation for more details on how to update a
>   bundle.

The first command fails:

```
bash-4.2$ git submodule add git://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips.git bundle/ultisnips
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

So I simply cloned the repository in bundle/ultisnips.

However, when I execute :help UltiSnips, vim doesn't find the help files. On the other hand, I can type ":" and autocomplete UltiSnips commands.

I would like to use some snippets and UltiSnips recommends the [default sinppets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

However, I really don't know exactly how to install it. Should I clone the folder in .vim/bundle/ also? I've found the documentation in /doc very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pathogen, you should be able to use

```
:Helptags
```

to install the documentation.  After that, `:help UltiSnips` should work.

Comment: It worked here. Thanks. 
 Please let me know if you know how to add the default snippets.

Comment: I do not use UltiSnips.  Follow the instructions there.  In your original post, you mention that some instructions assume you are already inside a git repository, and tell you to use `git submodule`.  You replaced that with `git clone`.  You may have to do that again.

Comment: The same error occurs. The README says "If you still have trouble getting this to work create a github ticket, ask on irc or the mailinglist.". But I don't know what's exactly the IRC channel nor what's the mailinglist. I don't find this information on the site. Anyway, I thought cloning the repository would work.